# Database for REST API with nested collections

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, rest

I was previously using GAE (Java) with Objectify but, it does not support nested collections. I need a database solution that will allow me to nest custom classes with collections of custom classes with collections of custom classes.

Does a PostgreSQL / Hibernate set up support such a thing. If not what database set ups do? I would like to interact with the database using Java, with maybe some annotations.

In the larger scheme of things this will be a RESTful webservice using Jersey and Spring. Resource, Service, Dao layer and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is very much possible using OR mapping tools like Hibernate. The following things needed to be kept in mind:

1. Databases will only have tables and relations. The Collections etc are on the application programming level.
2. **Object to Relational** mapping tools like hibernate, help you map the real world objects of programming languages to database tables.
3. For example, if there is a class called `School` with a collection called `Students` having individual elements as objects of  `Student` class.
4. Now this is a typical [`one-to-many`](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-xml-mapping-tutorial/) mapping. Check out the details of [available collection mapping strategies in hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html).
5. Same example can be further extended for each `Student` to contain a collection called `subjects` having individual elements as objects of `Subject` class. This maps your use case(*custom classes with collections of custom classes with collections of custom classes.*).